# Как запомнить имя пользователя?

Tags: python, бот

Я начинающий программист. В интернете искал ответ на вопрос, но не нашел. Я делаю свого бота на Пайтоне, и я хочу сделать так, чтобы программа запоминала имя пользователя навсегда. Тоесть, когда я запускаю программу, она приветствует меня именем пользователя, которое я ей дал. Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Сохранять в файл. Ну или просто записать в самой программе.

Comment: Где ваш код ...?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого можно использовать пару вариантов. Например, использование базы данных (просто создаем базу данных, и в ней одну таблицу с двумя полями: id(int) и name(text)). Либо же, как вариант, записывать в файл (например файл типа .json).